# Subsetting by logical vectors using subset function

Tags: r

I am trying to subset a dataframe (n=16070) based on county name, which is coded as a string variable. The dataset looks like the following:

```
county         asthma eviction_rate
Alameda        10      1.2
Contra Costa   12      3.2
Orange         9       9.6
San Francisco  1       4.5
```

I used the following code:

```
state_file <- subset(state_file, state_file$county != c('Alameda', 'Contra Costa'))
```

When I run the code, I get the following error message:

```
Warning message:
In state_file$county != c("San Mateo", "San Francisco", "Contra Costa",  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The output that I do get includes the aforementioned counties.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `%in%` and negate (`!`) as `==` is elementwise comparison, works only for a single element on the rhs of `==` or the same length as the lhs

```
subset(state_file, !county %in% c('Alameda', 'Contra Costa'))
```